# Передача значениe переменной из одного js файла в другой

Tags: javascript, global-variables

Есть файл `js` в котором есть переменная. Нужно передать значение этой переменной в другой `js` файл. Как это можно реализовать?

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  var bal = document.getElementById('bal').value;
  console.log(bal);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="bal">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Send">
```

Вот так в первом файле я беру значение переменной.

Comment: например, [`export let var = ...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) + [`import var from 'first.js'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) + [какой-нибудь](https://webpack.github.io/) сборщик

Comment: все Js-файлики на страничке выполняются как один, т.е. видят переменные друг друга. У вас же переменная локальная, соответственно, видна только в этой функции. Поясните, куда и с какой целью ее нужно передать

Comment: @selya я вообще пишу расширение, в его меню есть инпут, этот `js` файл отвечает за то, что бы считать значение инпута и отправить его в другой `js` файл который в свою очередь уже произведет с полученными данными какие то действия, скажем на сайте google.com